# Creating a Beamer Poster

Tags: beamer, miktex

I am trying to create a Beamer poster.

I'm using Texnic Center and normally packages install on the fly. When I tried to copy a paste a beamer template into Texnic Center, I got an emergency stop.

Is there anything I need to install to make it work? Using MikTeX by the way

Thanks

Comment: You need to install `beamer` and a lot of other dependencies. I suggest you to configure MikTeX to install from the Internet without asking you. Go to MikTeX options and then configure it.

Comment: Thanks @Sigur but how am I to do that. Is it via the MikTeX package manager page?

Comment: Yes. You can choose a repository over the Internet and then (if you setup it) it will install packages on the fly.

Comment: Does the emergency stop come with an error message of any kind?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang I was looking at the following webpage: https://www.overleaf.com/2129194yrxcfs#/5423422/ and literally just copied and pasted that into a plain latex document. I got 134 error messages! I have checked and the beamer package is installed, so not really sure why it isn't working

Comment: You probably forgot to copy the remaining files from that template. \usetheme{confposter} % Use the confposter theme supplied with this template Download the whole project as ZIP and compile it.